# Discord Bot Server Deafen

Tags: javascript, discord

I'm trying to mess with my friend so whenever he tries to user another discord bot command starting with "-", it deafens him so he can't hear it. I've been searching everywhere trying to find a solution but I wasn't able to find one that worked. I tried using the guild.fetchMember() function, but I'm not sure if I did it correctly so it didn't work. This is what I have so far (only the last function is in question):

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thYMJ.png)

Comment: please don't post screenshots of code, you can just copy paste it here.

Answer (score 0):

Friend, You can do this by

```js
bot.on("message", message =>{
// confirming that its your friend who is using the command.
  if(message.author.id != "your friend's id") return;
  if(message.content.startsWith("-")){
        message.guild.members.cache.find(member => member.id == "your friend's id").voice.serverDeaf;
  };
});
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. I get an error of  "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined." I get the same error but for startsWith if I nest if(message.author.id != "your friend's id") return; within the if below it, so I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Maybe, You could use it as `message.guild.members.cache.get("his id")`, And use your friend's name instead of id above. Just replace message.author.id with message.author.username.